# Tomcat 7 with Memcached Session Manager

Tags: java, tomcat7, memcached

We are setting up Tomcat 7 clusters and we need to use Memcached Session Manager to manage the session among multiple Tomcat 7 instances.

I have included the following 2 jar files into "/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/":
memcached-2.5.jar
memcached-session-manager-tc7-1.6.5.jar

And updated server.xml by including this:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/">
        <Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager" 
        memcachedNodes="n1:localhost:11211" sticky="false" lockingMode="all"
                    requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$" 
        transcoderFactoryClass="de.javakaffee.web.msm.JavaSerializationTranscoderFactory" />
    </Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
    prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
            pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

However, every time I tried to start the tomcat instance, I get this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/javakaffee/web/msm/MemcachedSessionService$SessionManager
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

Anyone can shed some light on which part has gone wrong will be very much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are missing following jar:

- [memcached-session-manager-${version}.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/javakaffee/msm/memcached-session-manager/)
- [spymemcached-2.11.1.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/spy/spymemcached/2.11.1/spymemcached-2.11.1.jar)

Please read the following link for more details: https://code.google.com/archive/p/memcached-session-manager/wikis/SetupAndConfiguration.wiki

Comment: to be exact, memcached requires (or consists of) 3 jars: 
memcached-session-manager-2.3.2.jar
memcached-session-manager-tc9-2.3.2.jar
spymemcached-2.12.3.jar
(In my case it is tomcat 9)